# How do I get a better result in NDSolve for 2D wave?

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

Consider the following equation solved with NDSolve:

```
op = -\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Del]\), \({x, y}\)]\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Del]\), \({x, y}\)] . {u[t, x, y], 
   v[t, x, y]}\)\) - \!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Del]\), \({x, y}\), \(2\)]\({u\ [t, x, y], 
 v[t, x, y]}\)\) + {D[u[t, x, y], t, t], D[v[t, x, y], t, t]};

Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], DX] = 
DirichletCondition[u[t, x, y] == 0, x == 0];
Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], DY] = 
DirichletCondition[v[t, x, y] == 0, x == 0];
Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], NX] = NeumannValue[1, x == L];
Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], NY] = NeumannValue[0, x == L];
\[CapitalOmega] = ImplicitRegion[True, {{x, 0, L}, {y, 0, A}}];

L = 1; A = 1;
{ufun, vfun} =
NDSolveValue[{op == {Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], NX], 
  Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], NY]}, Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], DX],
 Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], DY], u[0, x, y] == 0,
Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][0, x, y] == 0, v[0, x, y] == 0, 
Derivative[1, 0, 0][v][0, x, y] == 0},
{u, v}, {t, 0, 10}, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega]];

Plot[ufun[t, L/4, A/2], {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

The result is bad. How can I get a result closer to the analytical one?

@Nasser
Following are satisfactory results

analytic
[image]

numeric
[image]

My question is: What is the best result Mathematica can give me for problems like this with simple comands like NDSolve, DSolve..

I know how to do it with "low level.."

PS: This is my first question. I dont know why the code is weird in the site. My operator is:
[image]

It is a 2D wave propagation problem. It is a clamped bar with dimensions 1x1 excited by the step load 1 at its end.

Comment: Using `Method -> "FiniteElement"` will solve this as a stationary problem. See the [NDSolve Options for FEM tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementOptions.html) for explanation. You might also be interested in the [Acoustics in the time domain](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/Acoustics/AcousticsTimeDomain.html#509267359) as that has many examples of the Wave equation.

Comment: `How can I get a result closer to the analytical one?` can you show what the plot then should look like from the analytical solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are going to re-write your operator in inactive form. For that we rename your given operator

```
opO = -\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Del]\), \({x, y}\)]\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Del]\), \({x, y}\)] . {u[t, x, y], 
       v[t, x, y]}\)\) - \!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Del]\), \({x, y}\), \(2\)]\({u[t, x, y], 
     v[t, x, y]}\)\) + {D[u[t, x, y], t, t], D[v[t, x, y], t, t]};
```

Here is that same operator in inactive form:

```
op = {D[u[t, x, y], t, t], D[v[t, x, y], t, t]} + {
   Inactive[Div][-1 Inactive[Grad][u[t, x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}]
    + Inactive[Div][-{{1, 0}, {0, 0}}. Inactive[Grad][u[t, x, y], {x, y}], {x,y}]
    + Inactive[Div][-{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}. Inactive[Grad][v[t, x, y], {x, y}], {x,y}]
   ,
   Inactive[Div][-1 Inactive[Grad][v[t, x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}]
    + Inactive[Div][-{{0, 0}, {0, 1}}. Inactive[Grad][v[t, x, y], {x, y}], {x,y}]
    + Inactive[Div][-{{0, 1}, {0, 0}}. Inactive[Grad][u[t, x, y], {x, y}], {x,y}]
   }
```

Verify that these are the same:

```
Activate[op] - opO
{0,0}
```

Experiment a bit with the different possible formulations just get some insight into your operator. The form given is the one that works.

For more information on the inactive form [see the documentation on that](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementBestPractice.html#1585211872).

Next, we set up the rest:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
L = 1; A = 1;
dx = DirichletCondition[u[t, x, y] == 0, x == 0];
dy = DirichletCondition[v[t, x, y] == 0, x == 0];
nx = NeumannValue[1, x == L];
ny = NeumannValue[0, x == L];
reg = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {L, A}];
mesh = ToElementMesh[reg, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.005]
```

For a better resolution, refine the mesh.

Solve:

```
Monitor[
  {ufun, vfun} = NDSolveValue[{op == {nx, ny},
     dx, dy,
     u[0, x, y] == 0, Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][0, x, y] == 0,
     v[0, x, y] == 0, Derivative[1, 0, 0][v][0, x, y] == 0
     }, {u, v}, {t, 0, 10}, {x, y} \[Element] mesh,
    EvaluationMonitor :> (currentTime = Row[{"t = ", CForm[t]}])
    ]
  , currentTime];
```

Visualize:

```
Plot[ufun[t, L/4, A/2], {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Please take the time to read the finite element documentation available in product.